# Using UIView.animateKeyframes to animate CAShapeLayer properties

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm struggling to understand why the following key-framed animation doesn't perform as I expect. Here minuteClock is a subclassed UIView that is also a child view of the main view. minuteClock's horizontal position is set via an exposed constraint. minuteClock's own layer has a CAShapeLayer sublayer called borderLayer.

I'm trying to simultaneously animate the location of minuteClock and the fillcolor of that grandchild borderLayer. What I'm finding is that the keyframes work for the positioning but are ignored for the CAShapeLayer. That is, while the minuteClock moves to 100 half-way through the overall duration, I don't see borderLayer's fillcolor turn red. Instead it seems to just animates very quickly (like a quarter-second) to green.

```
       UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0,
                                delay: 0,
                                options: .calculationModeLinear,
                                animations: {
                                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0,
                                                       relativeDuration: 0.5,
                                                       animations: {
                                                        self.minuteClockPositionConstraint.constant = 100
                                                        self.minuteClock.borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                                                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                                    })
                                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5,
                                                       relativeDuration: 0.5,
                                                       animations: {
                                                        self.minuteClockPositionConstraint.constant = 50
                                                        self.minuteClock.borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                                                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                                    })

        }, completion: nil)
```

I think I'm probably going about this wrong, mixing up keyframed animation at the view level with implicit animation triggered by changing a property on a CAShapeLayer.

Any suggestions as to how I should be doing this?

Comment: “mixing up keyframed animation at the view level with implicit animation triggered by changing a property on a CAShapeLayer.” Exactly! You cannot use UIView animation to animate a CAShapeLayer. It is not a UIView!  You must use layer animation, that is, Core Animation. There is key frame animation at the Core animation level.